# Do All The Daedric Artifacts have to be collected with the same character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

I have been completing the Oblivion Walker trophy/achievement but in order to get one of the Daedric artifacts you must talk to Silus Vesuius. Unfortunately, I killed him a while back and I have no save near then. On another one of my characters I'm around that level where I can complete the quest.

If I get the artifact with that character (where I'd only have that 1) would it count towards the trophy with the other artifacts I have on my main character where Silus Vesuius is dead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Oblivion Walker achievement/trophy requires all the daedric artifacts (with the exception of the skeleton key, which doesn't count) to be collected in the same playthrough.

If you've missed one, you'll have to reload an earlier save or begin a new game to earn the trophy.

Comment: More information: You don't need to have all the artifacts at the same time, it is enought with having it at some moment in the playthrough. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49304/can-you-complete-oblivion-walker-if-youve-sold-misplaced-or-otherwise-no-long